# app goes to blank screen upon returning from 'open downloaded ics file in browser'

Tags: javascript, c#, android, asp.net-mvc

There's a link in my app, when clicked, an ics calendar event file is generated and returned from controller as ActionResult/File:

```
return File(memoryStream, "text/calendar", "calendar.ics");
```

the link looks like this:

```
<a href="/controllerName/MethodName?param=xyz">link</a>
```

Expect result is: click on the link, browser is opened with the file downloaded. When return to the app, stays in the same screen in the app.

This works as expected in IOS app, browsers in iOS and Android, but not in android app. In android app, click the link, browser is opened with the file downloaded, but when return to the app, it display a blank page, I need to click on back button twice to reach the old page. Not sure why? Seems like it makes some navigation because of the href?

To prevent the navigated to blank page in the app, I changed `<a>` to `<div>`, and `href=""` to `ng-click=syncCalendar()`, and use `$http.post()` to get the response from the same controller that returns the file above. The response I get is the content of the file, when I log it to console, it has correct content,displayed plain text in the console. And the app is not navigating to blank page anymore. This is the content of the `response`:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:...............
DTEND:20161022T110000
DTSTAMP:20161020T145537Z
DTSTART:20161022T104500
LOCATION:123 Test Drive\nNY\, NY 123456
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:xyz
UID:123-56h-78di-9dfgh
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Then I open the file from the javascript in my app with:

```
window.open("data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(response));
```

This also works in both browsers in iOS and Android. But does not work when tested in android app. The browser is not opened as expected. Not sure what's the problem, why it only doesn't work in android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a stupid line of code in my android native app.... I had this:

```
webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

uhhh, I've always thought it's a server side issue, didn't look at native side. So the moment I remove this code, it behaves all good.